# Target specific item in Accordion with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to link to a specific panel in my accordion from another page (e.g. `page.html#secondItem`). I have read I've to use `location.hash` but unsure how to in this example.

Can someone please advise.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/macamorasi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

```css
.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .accordion-content {display: none;}
  .accordion-content.default {display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle" id="firstItem">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content default">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle" id="secondItem">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-toggle" id="thirdItem">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/macamorasi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: That won't open the accordion though I don't think, and as hidden accordion items are `display:none` this will essentially do nothing. You'd have to read the url each time and check for hash, then check through all the accordion items then open it and then jump to it - I could be wrong though, there may well be a simpler solution

Comment: There is no ID of `secondItem` in your HTML, so which part of the accordion are you referring to?

Comment: Apologies. I'll update above :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `location.hash` exists. If it does, use it to find the element of interest and then slide it down. You can then use `.siblings()` to find other `<h4>` elements, and get their next neighbour and slide them up.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  // General accordion click toggle
  $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

  });

  // Check for location hash
  if(location.hash) {
    // Remove the first '#' character
    var hash = location.hash.substr(1);

    // Expand element 
    if($('#'+hash).length) {
      $('#'+hash)
        .next()
          .slideDown()
          .end()
        .siblings('h4')
          .next()
          .slideUp();
    }
  }
});
```

See the full code here: http://jsbin.com/bonozoqezo/1/edit. For a proper demo, access full screen demo with a hash: http://jsbin.com/bonozoqezo/1#secondItem

Comment: Thank you, Terry - I'll try this locally and let you know how I go :)

Comment: That worked beautifully, Terry. Many, many thanks for your time and skills - very much appreciated :)